# Controlling JQGrid horizontal scroll bar in ASP.NET MVC Application

Tags: asp.net-mvc, jqgrid, jqgrid-asp.net

I have come across a problem with my JQGrids horizontal scroll bar 
in an ASP.NET MVC application. The issue is, i have given a fixed width to the grid, and expect that horizontal scroll bar should appear dynamically when i resize my columns; but it does not, instead, the grid spills out of the page. I have tried to add a div element with overflow=scroll around the table which holds the grid, even that did not solve the issue.

Am i doing something wrong? I tried to dig through the existing threads, but could not find similar ones.

I have attached the HTML and Script code as a reference. Any help is appreciated.

```
<div id="div1" class="clsInner">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="2" class="clsHeading">
                Existing Proposals
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="2">
                <table id="list" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="scroll">
                </table>
                <%-- <div id="pager" class="scroll" style="text-align: center;">
                </div>--%>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="2">
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

and

```
 jQuery("#list").jqGrid({
     url: '<%= Url.Content("~/OrganizationAccount/AccountHomeGridData") %>/',
     datatype: 'json',
     mtype: 'GET',
     colNames: [
         'Id', 'Proposal Name', 'Proposal #', "", "", 'Organization', 'Category',
         'Sub Category', 'Status', 'Updated On', 'Updated By', 'Review', 'Edit'],
     colModel: [
         { name: 'ProposalId', index: 'ProposalId', width: 1, align: 'left' },
         { name: 'ProposalName', index: 'ProposalName', width: 180,  align: 'left' },
         { name: 'ProposalNumber', index: 'ProposalNumber', width: 72,
           align: 'left', resizable: false },
         { name: 'ProposalNumber1', index: 'ProposalNumber1', width: 1,
           align: 'left' },
         { name: 'ProposalNumber2', index: 'ProposalNumber2', width: 90,
           align: 'left' },
         { name: 'Organization', index: 'Organization', width: 150, align: 'left' },
         { name: 'Category', index: 'Category', width: 85,
           align: 'left', resizable: false },
         { name: 'SubCategory', index: 'SubCategory', width: 90, align: 'left' },
         { name: 'Status', index: 'Status', width: 100, align: 'left' },
         { name: 'LastUpdated', index: 'LastUpdated', width: 90,
           align: 'left', resizable: false },
         { name: 'UpdatedBy', index: 'UpdatedBy', width: 100, align: 'left' },
         { name: 'Review', index: 'Review', width: 50,
           align: 'center', sortable: false, resizable: false },
         { name: 'Edit', index: 'Edit', width: 40,
           align: 'center', sortable: false, resizable: false}],
     //pager: jQuery("#pager"),
     rowNum: 10,
     rowList: [10, 20, 30],
     sortname: 'ProposalName',
     sortorder: "asc",
     viewrecords: true,
     pginput: false,
     pgbuttons: false,
     rowList: false,
     imgpath: '<%= Url.Content("~/scripts/themes/sand/images")%>/',
     caption: 'Proposal Details',
     width: '980'
     //autowidth: true,
     //forceFit: false
 });

 jQuery("#list").hideCol("ProposalId");
 jQuery("#list").hideCol("ProposalNumber1");
 jQuery("#list").hideCol("ProposalNumber2");
```

Comment: Which version of jqGrid you use? Current version is 3.7.1. Parameter `imgpath`and class="scroll" were in a very old version which not yet supports jQuery UI thems. Do you use jQuery UI? Which version? And which version of jQuery?

Comment: You have problem with formating. So it would be important to know CSS definition of all parent classes of jqGrid: clsHeading, clsInner and so on.

Comment: Hi Oleg, thanks for looking into the issue. My current JQGrid version is 3.6 RC1, i took it when we started the project last year July, since then did not update it! I do use jquery UI and the version is 1.7.2 and JQuery version is 1.3.2. As you had pointed i checked the classes parent to the JQGrid table. They only change back-color and cell-padding as such, As, clsHeading { font-weight: bold; font-size: small; } and .clsInner { background-color: White; padding:5px; }

Comment: Also, i did try to get latest vesrion of the JQGrid and try, but no luck yet. Next time i will try new with new version of JQUery & UI too.

Comment: It is too late now in Germany. I will make some experiments tomorrow. Short information about the versions of jqGrid. There are some bugs in jqGrid version less then 3.6.5 with jQuery 1.4.x. If you plan use new versions of jQuery and jQuery UI you should use at least 3.6.5.

Comment: One thing is not quite clear for me. Do you have now NO horizontal scrollbar at the beginning or you HAVE one, but you don't want it. Or you have problems only after changing the column size with the mouse? 
One more general information about jqGrid. It has resizing feature  http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:jquery_ui_methods#resizable_grid, but to use it you have to include jQuery UI.

Comment: On page load, i DO NOT have the horizontal scroll bar, because the columns are evenly allocated. I want horizontal scroll bar to appear dynamically without grid itself spilling over, when i increase a column size. Also, i do not have chance to replace the JQuery UI files as they have been altered big time.
Today i tried to add event resizeStop to the grid thinking it can call setGridWidth method, but i could not get the event running in the first place.
I managed to get the grid not to spill over the page during column resize, by adjusting column widths, but not the complete solution.

Comment: Sorry but I can not follow you. In all my grids I try to have no scroll bar if it is possible. You do want have it. Why is it good? But to do this you can use `setGridWidth` method to set width a little less then the sum of widths of all grids columns. You can get  colModel with `getGridParam('colModel')`. Modification of the width you can do inside of `loadComplete` and `resizeStop` events.